# auto scroll based on scrollTop()

Tags: jquery

i'm still trying to grasp this stuff so some help would be appreciated

I have 5 div's all set with heights based off $(window).height()
I have set each div with a unique ID

i have some vars set

```
var wH = $(window).height();
var half-wH = (wH) / 2;
```

what i would like to do would be to have query scroll the window to each ID based on 50% of window.height either way

i.e. window height 600px
less than 300px scrollTo #id1
greater then 300px but less than 900px scrollTo #id2
etc. but only after a small delay

I know that if i use
.scrollTop() in combination with the 1st div #ID1
it'll show me the pixels scrolled from the top of my page

how i place it all together has me scratching my head!!

Comment: Probably a good idea to setup your example in http://jsfiddle.net/ :)

Comment: good idea  here it is  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N5U2j/15/)

Comment: you need to resize there browser window for the dimensions to be set for some reason,  doesn't happen outside of jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var st = $(window).scrollTop();
var elem = $('#id1').offset().top;
var elem2 = $('#id2').offset().top;

if(st < 300) {
   $(window).scrollTop(elem)
}

if(st > 300 && st < 900) {
   $(window).scrollTop(elem2) 
}
```

Comment: this is what i'm trying to do [here](http://www.beoplay.com/Products/Beolit12)

so far playing with you code i've got it to do and instant return to the document top but not a slide

Comment: that wasn't very good english

i've got a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N5U2j/15/) setup
i'd like to use a
  if(st < 300) {
    $("body").scrollTo("#ID1").delay(1000); }
  }

Comment: ok so more fiddling and i've got to this point

    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if(st < 300){
      $("body").scrollTo("#1", 2000).delay(2000);
    }
    else if(st > 300 && st < 900){
      $("body").scrollTo("#2", 2000).delay(2000);
      }
    else if(st > 900 && st < 1500){
      $("body").scrollTo("#3", 2000).delay(2000);
      }
    });
    });


but now no-matter whet the $(window).scrollTop(); number is  it scrolls back to the ID1 or whatever ID i set in the first 'if' condition

Comment: @Mat Mann you can use scrollTo() with jQuery objects, try updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

To use the JavaScript **scrollBy** and **setTimeout** methods to make a web page scroll down automatically. Change the timeout value to alter the scrolling speed in milliseconds.

```
function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
        scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}
```

To being scrolling automatically when the page loads, add the following code to the body tag:

```
<body onLoad="pageScroll()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(size < 300){
$(document).scrollTo("#id1"); }
else if(size > 300 && size < 900){
$(document).scrollTo("#id2"); }
```